# no way to catch Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using React js with firebase auth to authenticate user on a web app.
using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword` to create/sign-in user, and use `onAuthStateChanged` to get the current user.
let's say user has created account/signed in and then refreshes browser page while connected to internet, in this case as soon as the app runs, user gets subscribed again by `onAuthStateChanged` which is in a `useEffect` hook, until now everything is ok, the problem comes when the user has create account and goes offline and then refreshes the page, so now app throws this error:[image]

I tried to catch error like below code, but no result:

```
useEffect(() => {
 let unsubscribe
 try{ 
    unsubscribe = firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged( userInfo => {
    if(userInfo){
     const {uid:userId,email,displayName}=userInfo.multiFactor.user
     dispatch( setUser({userId,email,displayName}))
    }
  })
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    setError('You may are offline or have bad internet')
  }

   return unsubscribe
 }, [])
```

I also tried the way that firebase doc has suggested for errors like below, but yet no result:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged( userInfo => {
    if(userInfo){
      const {uid:userId,email,displayName}=userInfo.multiFactor.user
      dispatch( setUser({userId,email,displayName}))
   }
  },err=>console.log(err))

   return unsubscribe
}, [])
```

I've read firebase doc about `(auth/internal-error)` but it was not clear on how to catch and handle it.
Any help?

Comment: As a side note, don't forget to dispatch signed out users too (e.g. `dispatch(setUser(null))` or similar) as your current event handler ignores sign out events.

Comment: What lines are throwing the `auth/internal-error` according to the stack trace?

Comment: @samthecodingman i edited to add a photo of error.

Answer (score 0):

The `onAuthStateChanged` observer is primarily used to notify the observer code when a user becomes signed in or signed out for any reason.  It typically does not deal with errors.

If you want to know if the sign-in process failed, you should check for errors in the code that initiated the sign-in, which you aren't showing here.  Somewhere, you must be calling one of the sign-in methods, such as [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword), which does generate errors.  Or perhaps you are using [FirebaseUI Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui) to manage sign-ins, which has its own way of dealing with errors.

However, as you can see in the API documentation for [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged), you can pass an optional second argument which is a function that yields an error, but that is atypical to use, and it's not clear from the API docs how it works.  I suggest sticking to handling errors in the code that performs the sign-in as you see in the code in the documentation.

Comment: thanks to reply. but I mentioned sign-in/sign-up functionality is nice and the user is well handled  for them. my problem is the first time the app gets rendered and `useEffect` runs! in that case if user is offline app crashes with that error.

Comment: What crash are you referring to?  The SDK will not crash if no one has attempted to sign in yet.  Maybe you should edit the question to be more clear about the specific scenario are you are working with, and the steps anyone can take to reproduce it.  Please read about [how to create a minimal complete example on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: edited the question please recheck.